# WEBrick run on hanami 1.0.0 shows errors because of wrong inflection

Tags: ruby, hanami

I generated model with `hanami generate model stimulus`. Then I fixed "stimuluses" to "stimuli" in the migration file name and inside, the table name.

Everytime I load a page I get this error in the server console window:

[ROM::Relation[Stimuluses]] failed to infer schema. Make sure tables exist before ROM container is set up. This may also happen when your migration tasks load ROM container, which is not needed for migrations as only the connection is required (schema parsing returned no columns, table "stimuluses" probably doesn't exist)

I looked into the libraries and found that this functionality has Inflecto library. Then I tried both adding to hanami project this:

```
# /config/initializers/inflecto.rb
require 'inflecto'

Inflecto.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular('stimulus', 'stimuli')
end
```

And editing the defualt library file:

```
# gems/inflecto-0.0.2/lib/inflecto/defaults.rb
Inflecto.inflections do |inflect|
  ...
  inflect.irregular('stimulus', 'stimuli')
  ...
end
```

But the message is still there after restarting the server.

Is this something I should solve and if yes, how to do this?

**EDIT:**

Also tried:

```
# /config/initializers/inflector.rb
require 'hanami/utils/inflector'

Hanami::Utils::Inflector.inflections do
  exception 'stimulus', 'stimuli'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming we are talking about Hanami v1.0.0, right?

You nearly succeeded. What hit you is that initializers seem to be not loaded when executing hanami commands and [maybe a bug in code reloading](https://github.com/hanami/hanami/issues/787). So instead of an initializer put it into a file that gets loaded when hanami commands are executed or require the initializer file in such a place. E.g.,

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
require 'hanami/utils/inflector'

Hanami::Utils::Inflector.inflections do
  exception 'stimulus', 'stimuli'
end
```

and then in your environment file

```
# config/environment.rb
# ...
require_relative 'initializers/inflections.rb'
# ...
```

I'm not sure if that is a good place to put custom inflection rules, but at least it works.